# Set event handler method inside xaml tag

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any opportunity to set event handler inside xaml without using c#, powershell etc.?
For example I would like to set text of another control after click. Below is a "pseudo code" of what I want to do:

```
<Button Content="Set value = text1" OnClick="txt1.Text = text1" />
<Button Content="Set value = text2" OnClick="txt1.Text = text2" />
<Textbox Name="txt1" />
```

Comment: No there is not by default but you can write your own extension that allows you this. I will come up with an example for you if you wish. Just let me know :)

Comment: That's cool, but unfortunately I have to do this without extentions or writing code.. :/

Comment: You could use Triggers but then Binding wont get updated since Animations take over in dependency property value precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a solution with EventTrigger. Though it does not work with TextBox, because the Text-Property is not animatable, you could change the text of a textblock with some buttons without any code behind.

**But: This is not a nice solution**, and you should either use some short codebehind (preferable in an attached behavior) or a small viewModel where you bind to some property. The last one should be the cleanest solution, the codebehind is the shortest.

for feasability, here's the template with which you can change the Text of a Control with pure xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="Control">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="buttonValueText1" Content="Set value = text1" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        <Button x:Name="buttonValueText2" Content="Set value = text2" Width="50" Height="50"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBox" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="buttonValueText1" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Text1" KeyTime="0:0:0.1"/>
              </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

        <EventTrigger SourceName="buttonValueText2" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="textBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="Text2" KeyTime="0:0:0.1"/>
              </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>

      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can write inline c# in xaml. Altho that is just something you should rather be avoiding at all costs. If you absolutely have to, you could do something like:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button Content="Set value = text1" Click="InlineHandler" />
  <Button Content="Set value = text2" Click="InlineHandler"  />
  <TextBox Name="txt1" />
  <x:Code>
    <![CDATA[            
          private void InlineHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var btn = sender as Button;
            if (btn == null)
              return;
            txt1.Text = btn.Content.ToString() == "Set value = text1" ? "text1" : "text2";
          }
      ]]>
  </x:Code>
</StackPanel>
```

[MSDN Link - Code-Behind and XAML in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970568.aspx)

In simple terms, you're just defining the event handler inline in xaml than in the code-behind.

Again do **not** resort to this approach unless you're proving a point.

Comment: I like this solution, just because it works. But neither of the answers provided should be used in productive code anyway.

Comment: @Herm Yeh, that's why I stated it should **not** be used unless you're proving a point. In production code this entire approach would be at fault anyways. Use the framework the way it was intended to be used(either by a partial code-behind class or adopting MVVM) to save some future headaches :)

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea of how you maybe could solve this

```
<StackPanel>

    <ToggleButton Name="B1" Width="50" Height="50" Content="Text1"/>
    <ToggleButton Name="B2" Width="50" Height="50" Content="Text2"/>

    <TextBlock Width="50" Height="50" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Style.Triggers>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=B1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=B1, Path=Content}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=B2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding ElementName=B2, Path=Content}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing the XAML handler in PowerShell is a steep cliff.  Writing the whole UI isn't.  Myself and Joel Bennett (aka Jaykul) merged together two wildly popular solutions for this (WPK and PowerBoots) into [ShowUI](http://showui.codeplex.com/).

```
New-StackPanel {
   New-Button "Set Text Value 1" -On_Click { $textBlock.Text = 1 }
   New-Button "Set Text Value 2" -On_Click { $textBlock.Text = 2 }
   New-TextBlock -Name textBlock
} -show
```

Because PowerShell can coerce many more types than XAML, it's actually a lot more convenient for rapid development of a user interface.

Comment: Be careful when linking to your own solution - people might read it as spam.